# Qt Creator shows only android as the available kit

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I installed Qt Creator for creating desktop apps and it is showing me that it only has the android kit. How to fix this? How to get x86 kit?

[image]

Comment: click on add button and search qmake.exe :P

Comment: Yes! It is indeed

Comment: Where did you download Qt, you just installed it? give more information

Comment: I downloaded it from the qt website and yes, then I simply followed the on screen steps to install it.

Comment: You want to use it on Windows ? Desktop App ?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I have already done that. qmake is only available in athe following path: C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\android_armv7\bin

Comment: Have  you downloaded it from that link: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.1.exe or did you use the online installer?

Comment: @eyllanesc That's exactly where I downloaded it from. And yes, I used the offline installer.

Comment: I find it strange that you show android if you used that link, uninstalled and installed again

Answer (score 1):

You have to select your components in installation window, see this image:

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2015 x64 as compiler.

Answer (score 0):

That is auto detected toolkit. You can add manually toolkit with proper qmke and compiler set up. 
You can use precompiled Qt version to do windows build [Here](https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/?hsCtaTracking=f977210e-de67-475f-a32b-65cec207fd03%7Cd62710cd-e1db-46aa-8d4d-2f1c1ffdacea)

Go to section as 5.6.x Offline Installers for Windows host. If you install Qt 5.6.2 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2), then will autodetect MinGW tool kit for windows build.